# How to autoplay multiple youtube videos and muted them?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, mute

How can I autoplay **multiple** youtube videos and muted them? I have the code below but it is only for one video, what about multiple videos?

```
<div id="muteYouTubeVideoPlayer"></div>

<script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
    videoId: 'e3Nl_TCQXuw', // YouTube Video ID
    width: 560,               // Player width (in px)
    height: 316,              // Player height (in px)
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 0,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

For playing multiple youtube video you may use the player perameters from the api.
You will get all of the above from here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters